# Graphql-laravel returning blank array in postman

Tags: laravel, graphql

Graphql with Laravel returning a blank array on postman while its giving data in browser with Graphiql URL

[127.0.0.1:8000/graphiql BROWSER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM3fy.png)

[127.0.0.1:8000/graphql POSTMAN IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWcXN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put your params into `params` tab not in `body` in Postman so that it looked like this:

```
key = query; value = query(products{...}}
```

[image: chech this image]